# How to perform Google Add-on automated deployment/publishing?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

My team is trying to apply modern software engineer techniques in developing an editor add-on for Google Spreadsheet.

With clasp, typescript, jest, git, GCP and CircleCI we were able to achieve:

- local development with our preferred source code management;
- unit testing/tdd on our domain rules;
- manage add-on versions by clasp;
- observability with Stackdriver on GCP;
- with CircleCi, we create a pipeline that executes unit-tests, makes clasp push and versions the add-on with the commit hash as a description.

In addition, through Google Marketplace SDK, the add-on has been distributed privately in our domain, therefore it doesn't need Google approval.

***The point is:* we're looking for a way to add a step in our pipeline to, programmatically, update and manage our published add-on.**

e.g.: after the generation of a new version with clasp, how to put it in the App Configuration on GCP?

[gcp app configuration page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpiF9.png)

In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/update-published-add-on) there are only manual steps.

Thank you all =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some time in the future, it may be possible to use the:
G Suite Add-ons Cloud API
to automatically "deploy" an add-on.
https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes-overview

But I'm not sure what a "deployment" includes.

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this through the Google Cloud Deployment Manager:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/deployment-manager

https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs

I don't see a gcloud command category for the G Suite Marketplace.

The G Suite Marketplace SDK is solely a Web Based UI tool.  And even though there is a G Suite Marketplace API, it has no capability to create or update an editor add-on listing.
https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/reference/rest?hl=en_US

There are aspects of the Cloud Project that the editor add-on is attached to, that can be programmatically managed through gcloud commands, using the G Cloud Projects tool.  For example, you can set and update whether a user has permission to do certain things with the Cloud Project.  But all of those things are in a different category than publishing a G Suite Marketplace editor add-on.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects

The Cloud Project that the G Suite Marketplace SDK is associated with doesn't directly control the G Suite Marketplace SDK.
I would look at the Google Cloud Deployment Manager to see if there is a way to do this.  Other than the Google Cloud Deployment Manager, I haven't discovered any other leads that look hopeful.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alan. It looks like,  for now at least, there is no way to continuously deploy/integrate add-ons on GCP. It will always need a manual step (go to G Suite Marketplace SDK, and refresh the add-on version).

I found that Google is about to launch a beta version of Alternate Runtimes. It may help us address this need.

https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes-overview